# httpwebserver.stop() is not working in Java web server

Tags: java, web, port, httpserver

I'm confused on how can I prevent this error, when starting the button it works and there's no problem, but when I try stop the button with contains function stopping the httpserver, it says *"this.server is null"*. Is there anything wrong with my code?

Please see the image below which returns and error during executing the stop button

[image]

**Main.java**

```
package main;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
public class Main {
    public static int port = 8006;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            
        JFrame FRAME = new JFrame();
        JLabel LABEL  = new JLabel("Port");
        JLabel lbl_status  = new JLabel("STATUS");
        JLabel lbl_server  = new JLabel("SERVER");
        JTextField jfield = new JTextField("");
        JButton btnStart = new JButton("START");
        JButton btnStop = new JButton("STOP");
        JRadioButton http=new JRadioButton("HTTP"); 
        JRadioButton https=new JRadioButton("HTTPS"); 
        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
        ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("images/con_img.png");
        
        btnStart.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //your actions
                SimpleHttpServer httpServer = new SimpleHttpServer();
                SimpleHttpsServer httpsServer = new SimpleHttpsServer();
                String portserver = jfield.getText();
                
                port = Integer.parseInt(portserver);
                http.setActionCommand("http");
                https.setActionCommand("https");
                
                if (!portserver.isEmpty()) {
                    String url = group.getSelection().getActionCommand();
                    
                    if(url=="http") {
                        System.out.println("http");
                        httpServer.Start(port);
                        lbl_status.setVisible(true);
                        lbl_status.setText("Status : HTTP Successfully Connected to PORT " + port);
                        lbl_status.setForeground(Color.green);
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("https");
                        httpsServer.Start(port);
                        lbl_status.setVisible(true);
                        lbl_status.setText("Status : HTTPS Successfully Connected to PORT " + port);
                        lbl_status.setForeground(Color.green);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("Don't Leave a blank" + portserver);
                }
                
            }
        });
        
        
        btnStop.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //your actions
                

                String portserver = jfield.getText();
                
                
                if (!portserver.isEmpty()) {
                    String url = group.getSelection().getActionCommand();
                    
                    if(url=="http") {
                        SimpleHttpServer httpServer = new SimpleHttpServer();
                        lbl_status.setText("Status : http PORT " + port + " "+ "has been stopped");
                        lbl_status.setForeground(Color.red);
                        httpServer.Stop();
                    }
                    else {
                        SimpleHttpsServer httpsServer = new SimpleHttpsServer();
                        lbl_status.setText("Status : https PORT " + port + " "+ "has been stopped");
                        lbl_status.setForeground(Color.red);
                        httpsServer.Stop();
                    }
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("Don't Leave a blank" + portserver);
                }
                
                
            }
        });
        
        
        LABEL.setBounds(160,60,100,100);
        lbl_server.setBounds(150,165,100,100);
        lbl_status.setBounds(220,5,400,100);
        btnStart.setBounds(220,200,100,30);
        btnStop.setBounds(335,200,100,30);
        jfield.setBounds(220,100,215,30);
        http.setBounds(220,150,60,30); 
        https.setBounds(350,150,65,30); 
        
        lbl_status.setVisible(false);
        
        FRAME.setIconImage(img.getImage());
        FRAME.setSize(600,350);
        FRAME.setVisible(true);
        FRAME.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        FRAME.setTitle("HTTP SERVER MAIN");
        FRAME.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        

        group.add(http);
        group.add(https);
        
        FRAME.add(btnStart);
        FRAME.add(btnStop);
        FRAME.add(jfield);
        FRAME.add(LABEL);
        FRAME.add(lbl_server);
        FRAME.add(lbl_status);
        FRAME.add(http);
        FRAME.add(https);
        FRAME.setLayout(null);
    
    }
}
```

**SimpleHttpServer.java**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URLDecoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import com.sun.net.httpserver.Headers;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;

public class SimpleHttpServer {
    private int port;
    private HttpServer server;

    public void Start(int port) {
        try {
            this.port = port;
            server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(port), 0);
            System.out.println("server started at " + port);
            server.createContext("/", new Handlers.RootHandler());
            server.createContext("/echoHeader", new Handlers.EchoHeaderHandler());
            server.createContext("/echoGet", new Handlers.EchoGetHandler());
            server.createContext("/echoPost", new Handlers.EchoPostHandler());
            server.setExecutor(null);
            server.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void Stop() {
        server.stop(0);
        System.out.println("server stopped");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a new SimpleHttpsServer object at the stop button listener. Please try to remove these two rows.

> SimpleHttpServer httpServer = new SimpleHttpServer();

```
if(url=="http") {
    SimpleHttpServer httpServer = new SimpleHttpServer();
    lbl_status.setText("Status : http PORT " + port + " "+ "has been stopped");
    lbl_status.setForeground(Color.red);
    httpServer.Stop();
}
else {
    SimpleHttpsServer httpsServer = new SimpleHttpsServer();
    lbl_status.setText("Status : https PORT " + port + " "+ "has been stopped");
    lbl_status.setForeground(Color.red);
    httpsServer.Stop();
}
```